# Responsive four column table not rendering in Outlook (2010,2016)

Tags: html, css, outlook, salesforce-marketing-cloud

built the following HTML for an email I am deploying. When I test in Litmus, the email looks great on all platforms except for Outlook. It appears one of the columns (the row with four imgs) breaks in Outlook desktop). The second image ends up moving to a new row.

FYI yes I know the image html may be wonky, I removed the original images that I was using in order to post in this group.

This is what the email block should look like:

[image]

code:

```html
<!-- == Title Text And Three Column Section == --><table class="em_full_wrap" style="table-layout:fixed;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#F8F8FB">  <tr>
   <td valign="top" align="center">
    <table class="em_wrapper" style="width:640px;" width="640" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
     
      <tr>
       <td class="em_side15" style="width:0px;" width="40">
        &nbsp;</td><td valign="top" align="center">
        <table class="em_wrapper" style="width:560px;" width="560" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
         
          <tr>
           <td class="em_ptop" style="padding-top:40px; padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px;" valign="top" align="center">
            <table class="em_wrapper" style="width:560px;" width="560" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
             
              <tr>
               <th class="em_defaultlink" style="color: rgb(37, 13, 83); font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 22px; line-height: 27px; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: middle; height: 20px;" align="center">
                Header Text</th></tr><tr>
               <td class="em_defaultlink" style="color: rgb(37, 13, 83); font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 22px; line-height: 27px; font-weight: bold; height: 20px;" align="center">
               </td></tr><tr>
               <td class="em_defaultlink" colspan="3" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; color:#666666;" valign="top" align="center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</td></tr><tr>
               <td class="em_h30" style="height: 20px;">
               </td></tr><tr>
               <td valign="top" align="center">
                <table class="em_wrapper" style="width:520px;" width="520" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
                 
                  <tr>
                   <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <table class="em_wrapper" style="width:520px;" width="520" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
                     
                      <tr>
                       <td style="width: 130px; height: 20px;" valign="top" align="center">
                        <table class="em_wrapper" style="width:130px;" width="130" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
                         
                          <tr>
                           <td class="em_ptop" style="vertical-align: top; width: 130px; height: 30px;" align="center">
                            <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="" title=""><img alt="Resources to support your mental well-being." data-assetid="144028" src="http://image.em.com/lib/fe8e13727c640d7e76/m/5/image+holder.png" style="display: block; max-width: 127px; color: #000000; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; height: 65px; width: 95px; text-align: center;" width="95" height="65"></a></td></tr></table><!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
    <![endif]--><table class="em_wrapper" style="width:127px;" width="127" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right">
                         
                          <tr>
                           <td class="em_ptop" style="width: 130px; height: 30px;" valign="top" align="center">
                            <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="" title=""><img alt="Resources to support your mental well-being." data-assetid="144028" src="http://image.em.com/lib/fe8e13727c640d7e76/m/5/image+holder.png" style="display: block; max-width: 127px; color: #000000; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; height: 65px; width: 95px; text-align: center;" width="95" height="65"></a></td></tr></table><!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
    <![endif]--><table class="em_wrapper" style="width:130px;" width="127" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right">
                         
                          <tr>
                           <td class="em_ptop" style="width: 127px; height: 30px;" valign="top" align="center">
                            <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="" title=""><img alt="Resources to support your mental well-being." data-assetid="144028" src="http://image.em.com/lib/fe8e13727c640d7e76/m/5/image+holder.png" style="display: block; max-width: 127px; color: #000000; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; height: 65px; width: 95px; text-align: center;" width="95" height="65"></a></td></tr></table><table class="em_wrapper" style="width:130px;" width="130" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right">
                         
                          <tr>
                           <td class="em_ptop" style="width: 127px; height: 30px;" valign="middle" align="center">
                            <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="" title=""><img alt="Resources to support your mental well-being." data-assetid="144028" src="http://image.em.com/lib/fe8e13727c640d7e76/m/5/image+holder.png" style="display: block; max-width: 127px; color: #000000; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; height: 65px; width: 95px; text-align: center;" width="95" height="65"></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr>
               <td class="em_h20" style="height: 15px;">
                &nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
               <td class="em_h20" colspan="3" align="center">
                <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; color:#501CD2; padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle; height: 20px;"><span style="font-size:16px;"><a alias="CTA" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="" style="color:#501cd2;text-decoration:underline;" title="CTA">CTA</a></span></span></td></tr><tr>
               <td class="em_h20" style="height: 40px;">
               </td></tr><tr>
               <td class="em_defaultlink" style="color:#501CD2;font-family:'Montserrat', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;font-weight:bold;" align="center">
               </td></tr><tr>
              </tr></table></td></tr></table></td><td class="em_side15" style="width:40px;" width="40">
        &nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr></table><!-- == // END Title Text And Three Column Section == -->
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I have found in Outlook desktop that if the sum of the table column widths is exactly the width of the parent table Outlook will push one of the tables to another row. I would suggest reducing the column table widths to 128px.

You can also keep the column table width as is and try to use Outlook specific CSS to eliminate the horizontal margin | padding | border | spacing that Outlook is applying to the column tables.
https://stigmortenmyre.no/mso/html/concepts/ofconstyletable.htm?filter=mso-